# Styling parent iframe content from child iframe using pure CSS (No Javascript allowed)

Tags: css

I have been in a situation where I can access the child iframe only. There are some elements on the parent frame where I want them styled.

I am also not allowed to use Javascript. CSS is the only option left.

Can any tell me as how to access the parent frame elements using CSS?

Note: I have been through many similar questions but all in vain.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: It's all in vain purely because there is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: @DavidThomas In addition, I do not believe it is possible to influence a parent frame from an iframe, since it would result in serious security flaws.